# Numeric Up Down control?

Tags: html, asp.net

How can i make the page refresh when the numeric up down value changes?

```
<input type=\"number\" id=\"quantity\" name=\"quantity\" min=\"1\" max=\"5\" value=\"1\" runat="server">
```

Comment: using javascript

Comment: i can't find the javascript code to do it...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859212/increase-and-decrease-number-with-javascript-and-two-buttons-up-and-down/50859505